# Bootstrap slider with image and video using asp.net/c#

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, slider

Im trying to make a slider using bootstrap carousel slider.

My problem is a have trouble getting both image and video to show the right way in the slider.

Anyone have a tip? Should I only be using one Literal or two?

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in objNews.GetFirstImgOrVideo().Rows)
    {

        litFirstImg.Text += "<div class='item'>" +
                                "<img src='img/news/" + dr["fldSliderImg"] + "' class='img-responsive' />" +
                                "<iframe src='" + dr["fldSliderVideo"] + "'></iframe>" +
                                "</div>";



    }
```

I think this shows an image broken tag over the video...